# DFT with EMGU/OpenCV - I'm doing something wrong

Tags: fft, emgucv

I'm trying to run DFT in 4x4 blocks over this image (look closely, it's small) [image] It may be a bit too small to see, but it's a 4x12 pixel image. The first 4x4 square is a checkerboard pattern with each square having one pixel, the second 4x4 square is the same pattern with each square having two pixels, and the last 4x4 square is a black square.

The problem I have is that the frequency components I get are not what I expect at all. For example, for the first square I expect to have a DC component in the matrix, but it's not there. I figure I must be doing something wrong but I'm new to EMGU so I'm not sure what. Below is my code.

```
using (Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName))                
using (Image<Gray, float> gray = image.Convert<Gray, float>())
{
    int numRectanglesPerRow = image.Width / WIDTH;
    int numRectanglesPerColumn = image.Height / HEIGHT;

    for (int i = 0; i < numRectanglesPerColumn; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRectanglesPerRow; j++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(WIDTH * j, HEIGHT * i, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

            Image<Gray, float> subImage = gray.Copy(rectangle);

            Matrix<float> dft = new Matrix<float>(subImage.Rows, subImage.Cols, 2);
            CvInvoke.cvDFT(subImage, dft, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_DXT.CV_DXT_FORWARD, -1);

            //The Real part of the Fourier Transform
            Matrix<float> outReal = new Matrix<float>(subImage.Size);
            //The imaginary part of the Fourier Transform
            Matrix<float> outIm = new Matrix<float>(subImage.Size);
            CvInvoke.cvSplit(dft, outReal, outIm, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? I can't see anything wrong in your code, but I can't figure out the expected result myself either.

Comment: For the last, all black, square I would expect only a DC component. That is only one non-zero element at `[0, 0]`. For the first square Octave says its `[2, 2, 2, 2; 0, 0, 0, 0; -2, 2, -2, 2; 0, 0, 0, 0]`.